# Check authenticated http requests in HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, authentication, httprequest

What kind of event and property I can leverage to check whether a http request (client) is pass through ASP.NET authentication? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly refer to the below link for the methods & events of the HTTPModule

to handle the client request.

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020417.htm